# Build an IAsyncEnumerable using TaskCompletionSource

Tags: c#, ienumerable, taskcompletionsource, iasyncenumerable

I have a method that accepts an `IEnumerable` and returns it transformed using the yield operator. To transform one element of the enumerable, I need to first know the value of another element. Therefore, I thought of using a `TaskCompletionSource` to create something like a "promise".

The problem here is that this code results in a deadlock if anything other than "a" is the value of the first `TestFieldA`. One solution would be to order the enumerable before passing it into the method - in which case there is no need for `TaskCompletionSource` altogether. I would like to know however if it can be done without this. I also know that this can be done with some LINQ queries, but this would require enumerating the input several times, which I would like to avoid.

This is is what I'm trying to achieve. (Only works if the first `TestFieldA == "a"`)

```
class Test
{
    public string TestFieldA {get;set;}
    public int TestFieldB {get;set;}
}


private async IAsyncEnumerable<Test> Transform(IEnumerable<Test> inputEnumerable)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

    foreach(var input in inputEnumerable)
    {
        if (input.TestFieldA == "a")
        {
            tcs.SetResult(input.TestFieldB);
            yield return input;
        }
        else
        {
            input.TestFieldB -= await tcs.Task;
            yield return input;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea could be to return an enumerable of tasks instead of an `IAsyncEnumerable`. Something like this:

```
private IEnumerable<Task<Test>> Transform(IEnumerable<Test> source)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>(
        TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);

    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (item.TestFieldA == "a")
        {
            tcs.TrySetResult(item.TestFieldB);
        }
        yield return TransformItemAsync(item);
    }

    async Task<Test> TransformItemAsync(Test input)
    {
        var value = await tcs.Task.ConfigureAwait(false);
        input.TestFieldB -= value;
        return input;
    }
}
```

This would still create a deadlock problem if the caller attempted to await each task in sequence. To solve this problem the caller should have a way to await somehow the tasks in order of completion. There is something like that in Stephen Cleary's [`Nito.AsyncEx`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx) library, the extension method [`OrderByCompletion`](http://dotnetapis.com/pkg/Nito.AsyncEx.Tasks/5.0.0/netstandard2.0/doc/Nito.AsyncEx.TaskExtensions/OrderByCompletion''1(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(System.Threading.Tasks.Task(''0)))):

```
// Creates a new collection of tasks that complete in order.
public static List<Task<T>> OrderByCompletion<T>(this IEnumerable<Task<T>> @this);
```

You can also grab the source code from [here](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Tasks/TaskExtensions.cs) if you want.

Comment: Thanks, that's really useful. Very close to what I'm trying to achieve!

Comment: I am happy that I gave you ideas Charalampe! Although Damien_The_Unbeliever's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61525954/11178549) about buffering items until the correct one is found, is probably simpler to implement, and cheaper in terms of memory and CPU consumption.

Answer (score 2):

Your current plan seems to depend on being able to travel back in time. I'd suggest just storing unsuitable items in a queue (rather than yielding them) until you find the suitable item with `TestFieldA` value.

At that point, you dequeue all of the queued items, use the now found value and yield each in turn. Then yield the item with the desired `TestFieldA` value.

How you proceed from there is slightly unclear because I don't know what you want to do if a) another `a` item is found and b) what to do if no `a` item is found.

There's no need for `Task`(`CompletionSource`), `async` or `IAsyncEnumerable` here - you cannot yield anything until you've found your `a` value - unless you have access to a time machine.

---

Bear in mind also that iterators depend on having their callers repeatedly ask for new items to make forward progress - you pause at each `yield` until they do. So it would be risky in the extreme to consider trying to `yield` items early if the yielded items have anything "`Task`-like" about them; The caller might decide to `await` on one rather than continuing the enumeration you need them to.